# Understanding an odd looking C++ for loop?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I have just encountered some code and I'm not sure why it is done that way.

Note that this is quite old code, so `for (auto i : x)` is not an option.

The code is:

```
INT_PTR i,c;
for(i=0,c=m_array.GetSize();i<c;i++)
{
  // Do stuff, i & c are not changed inside the loop
}
```

Where as I would have done (well I would have used single letter variables, but thats another argument:

```
const INT_PTR c = m_array.GetSize();
for (INT_PTR i = 0; i < c; i++)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Is there some performance advantage of the first approach that I don't know about?

Comment: The two ways of doing it are identical, only difference being the scope of the variable i

Comment: I would say the performance "advantage" here is the developer typed less in the first case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once upon a time in some compilers long forgotten the first way was *the only way* in C.

In older dialects, including original ones , functions would be defined like this:

```
int foo(a, p) 
int a; 
char *p; 
{ 
}
```

and declared like this:

```
int foo(int , char ) ;
int foo2(); // unknown arguments
int foo3(void); // no arguments
```

Variables had to be declared before any other code happen and their life length and visibility was prolonged until function would return to its caller. The aforementioned syntax at first was the only one, later declaration was included into `for()` header but variables would be still visible outside. Great changes later came with ANSI and ISO standards.

In modern C and C++ the original style of for loop leads to visible variables that may stay uninitialized if `for()` didn't contain initialization and no iteration had happened. An advantage of it is that you can "initialize" variables of incompatible types even  before C++17 (the quotes are there because technically it's assignment and C++ throws in different rules for those):

```
float arr[] = { 3,4,5,6 };
int i, e;
float v;

for( i = 0, e = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]), v = arr[i];  i < e; v = arr[++i] )
{
}
```

At work as soon as I see some other programmer use C style of function design in C++ project, I begin to scrutinize that code. Sometimes they accidently introduce UB or incorrect behaviour because they apparently follow K&R C rules. Or had plagiarized it from somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there is a difference between the code examples. However, a "intelligent" compiler will optimize this anyway.

Comment: the difference is that in the first `i` is declared outside the loop and in the second `c` is `const`

Comment: Sure, but when the compiler recognize that `c` never changed, he handels this variable like a `const`.